# VScodeでMicroPyhtonとSympyは同時に使えない？

Tags: python, vscode, numpy, matplotlib, sympy

タイトルがわかりにくくてすみません。プログラミング初心者なので、どこが分からないか分からないに近い状態なのですが、ひとつひとつ説明していきますので辛抱強く読んでくださると嬉しいです。

#### バックグラウンド

私はEV３というLEGO社が出しているロボット組み立ての知育玩具で遊んでいます。これがなかなか本格的で、色んな言語でプログラミング出来ます。メソッドやクラスは先に設定されていて、それを組み合わせて付属パーツのモータやセンサを動かします。私の環境はmacOSで、エディタはVScode、言語はPython３です。VScodeではEV3専用の拡張機能がインストール出来ます。それをインストールして、そのフォルダの上でなにか書くと、Motorを動かすメソッドやセンサを設定するメソッドが補完に出てくるといった具合に、コーディングのための準備が整います。

```
#!/usr/bin/env pybricks-micropython
```

というのを一行目に書くと、補完が使えるようになります（？）

今まで私はそれでたくさんコーディングして、既存のメソッドだけで遊んでいました。

#### 目標

しかしながら内蔵されたメソッドだけで遊ぶのに飽きて、もっと難しいロボットを作りたくなりました。そこで、セグウェイを、ミニサイズですが、作ることにしました。制御工学という学問では倒立振子と呼ぶのですが、大学でそれを学んでいるので理論構築と設計は簡単でした。こいつを動かしたい、というのが目標です。

#### 生じた問題

いざセグウェイのプログラムを書こうとすると、ベクトル、行列、微積分などの処理をしなければなりません。しかし先ほど整えたEV3のためのフォルダには数値計算モジュールが入っていません。ですので行列も定義できません。そのフォルダに、

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot
```

と書いても、補完には全く現れてくれません。おまけに、`error: "sp" in not defined`とさえ出てきます。
私のイメージでは、sympyのメソッドなどと、EV３用のメソッドが同時にスイスイ使えるはずだったのですが、そのようにするにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？教えて下さい。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 実際に動作させる場合はEV3の中のMicroPythonなのだから、開発環境でも制限を掛けているのでは？ [EV3用MicroPythonでプログラミングしてみた　～レゴマインドストームEV3～](https://www.souichi.club/lego/ev3-micropython/) MicroPython関連記事 [Micropython Esp8266 Sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60450424/9014308), [ESP32用micropythonで、numpy, scipyライク...](https://dekuo-03.hatenablog.jp/entry/2020/04/12/190513), [MicroPythonで作る人工生命っぽい何か](https://www.slideshare.net/ikemkt/micropython-120905882), [NUMPY COMES TO MICRO PYTHON](https://hackaday.com/2019/10/29/numpy-comes-to-micro-python/)

Comment: ありがとうございます。リンクも見ましたが手順は間違っていないようです。開発環境でも制限を掛けている　というのは具体的にはどのような状態でしょうか？

Comment: このページ [用語集 - MicroPython 1.13 ドキュメント](https://micropython-docs-ja.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/reference/glossary.html) の`micropython-lib`、`upip`、`MicroPython Unix ポート`等の各用語の説明から推測される、MicroPythonで使えるモジュール/パッケージしかダウンロード/import出来ないようにしている可能性が考えられます。